# android - How to create xml's id?

Tags: android, xml, keyboard

I'm developing a dynamic keyboard application using soft keyboard sample. My application changes layout. For example I have a keyboard(has one key) then I set up the app and I can use keyboard(has one key).

I want to create an XML file after compilation and use this file in the application (reading XML file with xmlpullparser or xmlresourceparser). However, keyboard class needs XML's id. How do I create an XML id?

Answer (score 61):

It can be defined in `ids.xml` or any custom file like `constants.xml` inside your `res\values` folder.

Examples:

```
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="keyboard" />
</resources>
```

and can be accessed in the code as following:

```
R.id.keyboard
```

Comment: I get the error found tag id where item is expected when using the first method

Answer (score 24):

You can define ids using an `ids.xml` file in your res/values directory. Here's an example:

```
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="my_keyboard" />
</resources>
```

In code, you would set the id like so:

```
keyboardView.setId( R.id.my_keyboard );
```

Comment: Is your answer set id for keyboardView?

Comment: You're asking how to create resource IDs for XML elements, right? Or did I misunderstand.

Comment: see here: https://developer.android.com/samples/ActionBarCompat-Basic/res/values/ids.html

Answer (score 2):

XML files are compiled (binary XML) and thus you don't create them at runtime.

If you want to change your keyboard layout dynamically, you'll do that programmatically rather than in XML.