# Google Pre-Launch Report with NativeScript Angular Login Screen

Tags: google-play, angular2-nativescript

I have an app with a login screen which I coded using NativeScript Angular. I want to use Google Play Pre-Launch Report function. Sign-in Credentials section of Settings page indicates that I need to enter Android resource names of username field, password field and sign-in button.

My question: Where can I find these resource names on NativeScript? Or how can I set them on my TextFields and Button?

Here is my login screen html:

```
<StackLayout>
  <TextField hint="Email" keyboardType="email" [(ngModel)]="user.email"></TextField>
  <TextField hint="Password" secure="true" [(ngModel)]="user.password"></TextField>

  <Button text="Login" (tap)="submit()"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57446506/935546 this answer can help.